# Is the Furtive Pygmy dark souls 2 invasion a special event or a player character?

Tags: dark-souls-2

So, I was playing in the Iron Keep doing some pVp, and had decided to quit when I tried to log out and couldn't. I hadn't activated any invasion signs and got invaded by a dark spirit "Furtive Pygmy". What's weird is the invader didn't have the tell-tale red glow like regular invaders do. Additionally the furtive pygmy had a "special" face in that wasn't a typical face you could get in the character generator, or the look of a hallowed PC, it had some sort of scabbing and growth over the left side of it's face, which I don't remember being possible to make. The character had no armor (just a loincloth) and a big freaking spear that it quite decidedly womped me with. Additionally, there didn't seem to be any network lag at all, which is weird since I'm playing via wireless carrier, which made me think it was an in game invasion.

While I realize that it may just be a player character named "Furtive Pygmy" (which unless he logged in and answered directly would be very difficult to verify), I'm curious if this is an NPC invasion. Given the nature of the Furtive Pygmy in dark souls lore, it'd be very interesting it it were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

There is no "Furtive Pygmy" anywhere in the game. Not even a hidden reference. It's likely a hacker, with a modded character appearance.

Comment: That's a bummer, it was actually really cool. Given the timey-wimey nature of the game's plot world it wouldn't be that far of a stretch for it to be a random invasion.